# Is it possible to change PyCharm's Jupyter Notebook's preview pane's background color?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to change Jupyter preview pane to match my IDE's background color? No matter how I change my themes or color schemes Jupyter's preview pane's background color remains the same (brown).

[image]